# Roslyn Analyzers do not run often enough

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing my first Roslyn analyzers. I have basically followed the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/special-issue/csharp-and-visual-basic-use-roslyn-to-write-a-live-code-analyzer-for-your-api , and then proceeded by adding a second analyzer class which should be language-agnostics analysis, similar to what presented in https://www.meziantou.net/writing-a-language-agnostic-roslyn-analyzer-using-ioperation.htm .

So, I have one analyzer class which initializes itself with

```
context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SymbolKind.NamedType);
```

and a second one which uses

```
context.RegisterOperationAction(AnalyzeConversionOperation, OperationKind.Conversion);
context.RegisterOperationAction(AnalyzeInvocationOperation, OperationKind.Invocation);
```

To test my analyzers, I have the generated .Vsix project set as startup project, and by pressing F5, it gets me to a separate instance of Visual Studio where I write some code and want to see whether my analyzers work as intended. And, I set breakpoints at the begininng of my analyzer actions - AnalyzeSymbol, AnalyzeConversionOperation and AnalyzeInvocationOperation, in the original VS instance.

The analyzer actions are not called as I would expect them too. In fact, they are not being called at all, as I write the code to be analyzed. Only if I place the cursor on some type name (which is related to the SymbolKind.NamedType action), *and* I click on the lightbulb that appears, I get the calls - and not only to the AnalyzeSymbol action, but also the AnalyzeConversionOperation and AnalyzeInvocationOperation are called as needed for various operations in the code.

So, the actions that get called are all fine - but they not called when I want them. I would expect them to be called as needed - basically, almost continuously as I edit the code. Or at least upon build, or some explicit "Analyze Now" command. But I am not aware of anything alike. The only way I found to trigger them is the way I described. That does not seem correct to me.

I tried Googling but could not find the solution; or possibly I have some misconception and it is supposed to work differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzers are run out of process. So I think it's expected that you don't get the breakpoints hit, but in fact these lines get hit.

You have three options:

- Disable running analyzers out-of-process.

  [image]
- Attach `ServiceHub.RoslynCodeAnalysisService` process to the debugger.
- Debug through a unit test. This is my preferred approach.

Comment: Thank you, but I think you have misunderstood. My problem is not about debugging. I can debug just fine. My problem is that the analyzer's don't run unless I do the action described in my question. They behave like this with or without the debugger. The part where I have described the behavior in debugger just provides more information about what is happening inside.

Comment: Without the debugger, how did you know the callbacks are not called. Are you reporting a diagnostic that you don't see as you type? It would be more helpful if you provided a repro project.

Comment: The problems happens already with the project I started with, i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/special-issue/csharp-and-visual-basic-use-roslyn-to-write-a-live-code-analyzer-for-your-api . My further modifications to the project only make it more apparent what is happening. Without the debugger, I can see that the analyzer does not show any warning until I make the "special" UI steps described. With the debugger, effects in the VS are the same, and I can see that the analyzer "action" are also only called at that moment.

Comment: I have found the issue. In the end, I am accepting this answer, because it is correct - except that it was not mentioning some important "glitches" that were confusing me so much: 1) At least in VS2022, the default behavior is different from what the Microsoft article I referenced describes: running analyzers out-of-process is the default behavior, so without turning it off the debugging described in the article does not work well. But, more importantly, 2) if the analyzers are set to run in separate process, they STILL sometimes run in the Visual Studio process. They do run in context of

Comment: ... invoking that "light-bulb", at least. And that is what caused the confusion, because one can put breakpoints in the analyzers and the debugging stops there - but since it is debugging in the VS process, it is not called as expected, i.e. basically after every code change that affects the analyzer.